# Laravel localhost works, but heroku gives 500 error

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, heroku

I'm working in a project that needs to convert some data from excel to database. This is working fine in local host with laravel, but when goes to heroku, it gives me a 500 internal server error.

I searched in heroku for something that point what could be, then I discovered that the heroku's database has 2 values inserted from the requests. So it means that the code loops twice, but then the error occurs.

I tried to find the error in the code for 4 hours, and I didn't found what is going on...

Here is the code:

```
public function insertFromExcel(){

        $excel = new \Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel();

        $data = $excel::load('../../../excel_files/relacao_5.xls', function ($reader) {

        })->get();

        foreach ($data as $row) {


            //-----------------------------------------Verifica Setor-------------------------------------

            if(isset($row['nome_setor'])){
                $setor_id = DB::table('setor')->where('nome', '=', $row['nome_setor'])->pluck('id');

                if ($setor_id == null) {
                    $setor_id = DB::table('setor')->insertGetId([
                        'nome' => $row['nome_setor']
                    ]);
                }
            }
            else{
                $setor_id = null;
            }

            //-----------------------------------------Verifica Funcionario--------------------------------

            $funcionario_id = DB::table('funcionario')->where('matricula', '=', $row['codfun'])->pluck('id');



            if ($funcionario_id === null) {
                $funcionario_id = DB::table('funcionario')->insertGetId([
                    'nome' => $row['nome_func'],
                    'matricula' => $row['codfun'],
                    'pis_pasep' => $row['pis_pasep'],
                    'data_admisao' => $row['admissao'],
                    'setor_id' => $setor_id
                ]);
            }
            else{

                $funcionario_pis_pasep = DB::table('funcionario')->where('matricula', '=', $row['codfun'])->pluck('pis_pasep');

                if($funcionario_pis_pasep == null || $funcionario_pis_pasep == 0){
                    DB::table('funcionario')
                        ->where('id', $funcionario_id)
                        ->update([
                            'pis_pasep' => $row['pis_pasep']
                        ]);
                }



                $funcionario_setor = DB::table('funcionario')->where('matricula', '=', $row['codfun'])->pluck('setor_id');

                if($funcionario_setor == null){
                    DB::table('funcionario')
                        ->where('id', $funcionario_id)
                        ->update([
                            'setor_id' => $setor_id
                        ]);
                }
            }


            //-----------------------------------------Verifica Cargos--------------------------------

            if (strpos($row['descrnivcarg'], "GERENTE") !== false) {

                $gerente = DB::table('gerente')
                    ->join('funcionario', 'gerente.funcionario_id', '=', 'funcionario.id')
                    ->where('funcionario.id', '=', $funcionario_id)
                    ->pluck('gerente.id');

                if ($gerente == null) {
                    $user_id = DB::table('usuario')->insertGetId(['senha' => '12345', 'nivel' => 3]);

                    DB::table('gerente')->insert([
                        'funcionario_id' => $funcionario_id,
                        'usuario_id' => $user_id
                    ]);
                }
            }
            if (strpos($row['descrnivcarg'], "COORDENADOR") !== false) {

                $coordenador = DB::table('coordenador')
                    ->join('funcionario', 'coordenador.funcionario_id', '=', 'funcionario.id')
                    ->where('funcionario.id', '=', $funcionario_id)
                    ->pluck('coordenador.id');

                if ($coordenador == null) {
                    $user_id = DB::table('usuario')->insertGetId(['senha' => '12345']);

                    DB::table('coordenador')->insert([
                        'funcionario_id' => $funcionario_id,
                        'usuario_id' => $user_id
                    ]);
                }
            }
            if (strpos($row['descrnivcarg'], "SUPERVISOR") !== false) {

                $supervisor = DB::table('supervisor')
                    ->join('funcionario', 'supervisor.funcionario_id', '=', 'funcionario.id')
                    ->where('funcionario.id', '=', $funcionario_id)
                    ->pluck('supervisor.id');

                if ($supervisor == null) {
                    $user_id = DB::table('usuario')->insertGetId(['senha' => '12345', 'nivel' => 2]);

                    DB::table('supervisor')->insert([
                        'funcionario_id' => $funcionario_id,
                        'usuario_id' => $user_id
                    ]);
                }
            }
            if (strpos($row['descrnivcarg'], "ESTAGIARIO") !== false) {

                $estagiario = DB::table('estagiario')
                    ->join('funcionario', 'estagiario.funcionario_id', '=', 'funcionario.id')
                    ->where('funcionario.id', '=', $funcionario_id)
                    ->pluck('estagiario.id');

                if ($estagiario == null) {
                    $user_id = DB::table('usuario')->insertGetId(['senha' => '12345', 'nivel' => 1]);

                    DB::table('estagiario')->insert([
                        'funcionario_id' => $funcionario_id,
                        'usuario_id' => $user_id
                    ]);
                }
            } else {
                $cargo_id = DB::table('cargo')->where('nome', '=', $row['descrnivcarg'])->pluck('id');

                if ($cargo_id == null) {
                    $cargo_id = DB::table('cargo')->insertGetId(['nome' => $row['descrnivcarg']]);
                }


                $operario = DB::table('operario')
                    ->join('funcionario', 'operario.funcionario_id', '=', 'funcionario.id')
                    ->where('operario.id', '=', $funcionario_id)
                    ->pluck('operario.id');

                if ($operario == null) {

                    DB::table('operario')->insert([
                        'funcionario_id' => $funcionario_id,
                        'cargo_id' => $cargo_id,
                    ]);
                }
            }
        }

        $funcionario_db[] = DB::table('funcionario')->select('matricula', 'nome', 'data_admisao', 'pis_pasep')->get();

        return $funcionario_db;

    }
```

Answer (score 32):

Set 2 config variables in heroku with following commands:

1 `heroku config:set APP_DEBUG=true` 
2 `heroku config:set APP_KEY=RandomString`

After setting these keys you will be able to see the actual error instead of general 500.

Comment: Which laravel version you are trying to deploy on heroku

Comment: I am using  6.5.1 laravel version

Comment: Somehow it is a database connection issue, However I created a postgresq and it is still not working

Comment: It worked after changing htacss file, can you please help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60135473/why-api-php-and-web-php-routes-file-not-working-on-heruko

Comment: @svikramjeet after run these commands from where we can see our actual error , are you taking about heroku logs -t ?

Comment: @HumayunNaseer : I would suggest you add addon like pointDNS with the free plan, but yes you can check log with `Heroku logs -t` and the endpoint will start showing error as well.

Answer (score 8):

For problem with key in heroku add this code in config/app.php:

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'SomeRandomStringSomeRandomString'),
```

In terminal write this command

```
heroku config:set APP_KEY=SomeRandomStringSomeRandomString
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this `heroku config:set APP_DEBUG=true` then visit your app and see what's exactly is the error. Most likely is database connection failing or missing `.env` key.

Comment: Saved me! Exactly what I needed

Answer (score 3):

After some more hours trying to figure out what is going on with the code, I discovered that it was a problem with the Apache timeout.

I found the answer [here](http://blog.voltampmedia.com/2014/09/02/php-apache-timeouts-post-requests/).

Credits: [Eric Cope](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256484/eric-cope)

Answer (score 3):

I discovered the why I had the 500 error. It was because I was putting date configuration wrong.

So, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy) solved my problem.

During the study to find the error, I discoverd that laravel has a debug messages when deploy too. So I change the debug mode to true.

directory: "laravel/config/app.php"

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Debug Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
    | stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
    | application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
    |
    */

    'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),
```

Answer (score 0):

On your heroku dahsboord, click on `more`, then `run console` then type `php artisan key:generate`
Also, in your heroku settings, click on reveal `config vars` add `APP_DEBUG` `true`